# Changing content of a div with clicking on a div [jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change the content of the portfolio section of my website. I have a div called .portfolio_box, which contains a small preview of the project (each project div also has a different id). When you click on this div (.portfolio_box) I want the content of the content div (#main_content) to go away and be replaced with the corresponding content.

I found [the following tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-load-in-and-animate-content-with-jquery/) and adjusted the script to my needs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {  
        $("#thomasschoof_old").click(function()
        {  

            /*hide( 'fast', function() 
            { 
                $('#main_content').load(thomasschoof_old.html,'',showNewContent); 
            } );

           var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #main_content';  */
            $('#main_content').hide('fast',loadContent);  
            $('#page').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');  
            $('#load').fadeIn('normal'); 

            }); 

            function loadContent() 
            {  
                $('#main_content').load('thomasschoof_old.html #project','',showNewContent)  
            }  

            function showNewContent() 
            {  
                $('#main_content').show('normal',hideLoader);  
            }  

            function hideLoader() 
            {  
                $('#load').fadeOut('normal');  
            } 
            return false;           


    });  
</script>
```

But when I click on the div #thomasschoof_old nothing happens. I don't know a lot about jQuery or Javascript (just getting into it) and I really can't get it figured out.

You can view the web page here: http://jowannes.com/thomasschoof/portfolio.html

I hope somebody can help me, Thanks in advance!
Thomas

Comment: You are defining a function inside the click event? Awesome! :)

Comment: That's the way it's handled in the tutorial I used to base this on, I guess that's wrong? (It seemed odd at the time...)

Comment: @PraveenKumar Well, most other jQuery users would have used an anonymous function, directly where it called; e.g. `hide( 'fast',  function() { $('#main_content').load(thomasschoof_old.html,'',showNewContent); } ); ` That is the jQuery way of life…

Comment: @feeela I may be wrong. But this part is a definition. It works in standard browsers. Not sure about IE. That's why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is, that you wrote your JS code inside scripts tags that are used to load an external script file (jQuery). You script just wont ge executed that way.

> **src**: This attribute specifies the URI of an external script; this can
>   be used as an alternative to embedding a script directly within a
>   document. **script elements with an src attribute specified should not
>   have a script embedded within its tags.**

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Script

Set up a separate script tag for you code or include it from a second external script-file and see what happens.

Comment: This got it 'working', the click event is now called! The new content isn't being loaded yet (the whole div disappears and only the background comes back :P)